# Can't write in other language in my login form

Tags: javascript, html, web, shiny, shiny-server

I created a login to my site. That you need to enter username and password:

[image]

All is working fine. But the problem is when i write in Hebrew (without clicking the login button) it immediately send an error.

**Fiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/L8ynedar/2/

**HTML Code**:

```
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 </head>

<body>
<section class="container" id="overlay">
  <div class="login" id="overlay">
    <h1>Barometer Login</h1>
    <form method="post" >
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" required="required" >
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" required="required" >
      </p>
      <p class="remember_me"> </p>
      <p class="submit">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:purple;" onClick="SignInFunction(this.value)" name="commit" value="Login">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function SignInFunction(val){
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value; 
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value; 

 if(username=="Anna" && password=="123"){ 
   document.getElementById("AftetLogin").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
 }  
}
```

After a lot of debugging. I found that, no matter where i am writing in Hebrew There is a alert bug of javascript.

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Comment: The Error: The application unexpectedly exited. I will edit my question and will write the code.

Comment: Can you put the `<meta>` tags too ? And how is the error send to you ? `alert`, `console.log`, element appearing on the DOM ? How are you checking the login ? `Javascript`, `Ajax` ?

Comment: @Seblor the bug is giving in alert and not writen in console.log. Yes I made the code by myself, No i Don't use Ajax.

Comment: How is the script giving you an `alert` if you made it all by yourself ? I don't see any `alert` script here. Is it a browser/JavaScript native `alert` ?

Comment: @Seblor I didn't understand you, the web app is giving me an error alert.

Comment: But how can your app give you an `alert` ? There is no `alert()` in your code. Can you create a JSFiddle to reproduce the error ?

Comment: @Seblor https://jsfiddle.net/L8ynedar/2/ but there are a little bit changes: i change my input-login to button-login.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what the problem come from. Put the JSFiddle in your post.

Comment: What browser are You using? The fiddle works fine with Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m.

Comment: @tiblu I am using with Chrom 42.0.2311.135

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya I updated Chrome to 42.0.2311.135 m. Still no issues. 
If you have many Chrome add-ons installed, try disabling them and see if the issue goes away?

Comment: @tiblu There is no Chrome add installed that working.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya Oh well, then I have no other ideas. Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: After a lot of debugging i found that no matter where i am writing in Hebrew. There is a alert bug of javascript.